# How to fold C++-style comments in Vim?

Tags: vim

Syntax folding in Vim makes it easy to create folds for regions, the start and end of which can be defined with regular expressions:

> syn region myRegion start="#region" end="#endregion" transparent keepend extend fold

However, I am not sure how I can use syntax folding to define folds for C++-style comments, which are sets of lines beginning with "//".

Comment: Why do you need to fold comments starting with "//" ? Those are one-line comments and they should be minimalistic and short so they don't need to be folded. You should fold only comment blocks starting with "/\*" and ending with "*/" and that should be easy to implement. According to your post this should be valid: syn region CommentBlock start="/*" end="*/" transparent keepend extend fold

Comment: Many coding standards use "//" for block comments. MSDN uses these throughout. Besides, there are other things one might want to fold that fall into the same pattern, such as "#include" and "using" statements.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I found a solution:

> :syn match comment "\v(^\s*//.*\n)+" fold

This is a multiline match that folds consecutive lines beginning with whitespace and double slashes. The "\v" in the beginning labels the pattern "very magic" for brevity. Seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

To fold multiple line comment blocks, with foldmethod=indent you must use expresion and recode indent folding. Try this in your vimrc.

```
set foldmethod=expr
set foldexpr=FoldMethod(v:lnum)

function! FoldMethod(lnum)
  "get string of current line
  let crLine=getline(a:lnum)

  " check if empty line 
  if empty(crLine) "Empty line or end comment 
    return -1 " so same indent level as line before 
  endif 

  " check if comment 
  let a:data=join( map(synstack(a:lnum, 1), 'synIDattr(v:val, "name")') )
  if a:data =~ ".*omment.*"
    return '='
  endif

  "Otherwise return foldlevel equal to indent /shiftwidth (like if
  "foldmethod=indent)
  else  "return indent base fold
    return indent(a:lnum)/&shiftwidth
endfunction
```

The last block :

```
indent(a:lnum)/&shiftwidth
```

Returns a foldlevel base on indent.

And the other one :

```
join( map(synstack(a:lnum, 1), 'synIDattr(v:val, "name")') )
```

Checks if the first character of the line is consider as a comment with the syntax. So it is a good way to merge indent and syntax folding with expression, the most advanced folding.

Note that you can also "set foldtext" depending on how you want the result to look like.