# How can I use Vim syntax files to collapse single line comments into one region?

Tags: vim, syntax, region, fold

I'm putting together a syntax for editing Java Manifest files ([at github](http://github.com/alblue/vim-manifest), if anyone's interested). I'm trying to collapse multiple single-line-comments (which I'm matching at the moment with `syntax match manifestComment "#.*"`). However, if I try to use a syntax region, then the entire file is marked and the entire thing collapses.

What I'm trying to achieve is this:

```
# A comment
# Another comment
# A third comment
Manifest-Version: 1
```

and have it collapse down into:

```
+--  3 lines: # A comment ----
Manifest-Version: 1
```

The problem is that there's no distinct 'end' character, and the fold syntax doesn't help; so I can't do `syntax region commentBlock start="^#" end="^[^#]"`. Roughly, the syntax region should start from the first hash character, and then continue down the lines until it finds a line which doesn't begin with a hash.

Comment: Closely related: [How to fold C++-style comments in Vim](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1280514/834176).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
:set foldmethod=expr
:set foldexpr=getline(v:lnum)[0]==\"#\"
```

For information, `:h fold-expr`.

Comment: Note that this should then go in a filetype plugin (:help ftplugin)

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a go and report back.

Comment: This seemed to work. However, if I used 'set' then it affected other files/buffers that I had open. I found that I needed to use 'setlocal'. In addition, even if I put the 'setlocal' in the ftdetect, then it would be invoked for any other script as well.

The solution I went with is to use this, but with 'setlocal' in the manifest, as here:

http://github.com/alblue/vim-manifest/blob/c40978f6fd119d2f904759be80491893d22870f2/syntax/manifest.vim

Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 1):

How about `syntax region commentBlock start="^#" end="^#\@!"`?

The `\@!` is like `(?!pattern)` in Perl, i.e. it matches with zero-width if the preceding atom -- `#` in this case -- does not match at the current position.

Comment: I didn't have much success with this one; or at least, I didn't manage to get it to work. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong? The syntax file is at http://github.com/alblue/vim-manifest/blob/master/syntax/manifest.vim - and I tried replacing line 15 with this one, but even with :set foldmethod=syntax, I couldn't get them to fold as one. It didn't even find any regions.

Comment: It turns out you need to add the `fold` argument, i.e.: `syntax region commentBlock start="^#" end="^#\@!" fold`.  And, as you pointed out, set the `foldmethod` to `syntax`.  There's more info at `:h syn-fold`.

Having said all that, I prefer kemp's `foldexpr` solution ;)